# Mapbox geojson data driven linear colors

Tags: typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to draw custom routes with Mapbox.

In my current version each route is drawn from a geojson file and each route gets its own color with the Mapbox datadriven aproach. My result so far:

[image]

However I'm struggling for a while now to make each route end fade into the next color. Like so:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

**My code so far:**

```
const helsinki = { lat: 60.1699, lng: 24.9384 };

    const valuesAndColors = [
      0,
      '#3435ae',
      100,
      '#59c9dd',
      200,
      '#c95cc6',
      300,
      '#37e328',
      400,
      '#ebda33',
      500,
      '#d01913',
    ];

    map.value = new Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
      center: helsinki,
      zoom: 5,
    });

    map.value.on('load', () => {
      // 'line-gradient' can only be used with GeoJSON sources
      // and the source must have the 'lineMetrics' option set to true
      map.value.addSource('line', {
        type: 'geojson',
        lineMetrics: true,
        data: routes,
      });

      // the layer must be of type 'line'
      map.value.addLayer({
        type: 'line',
        source: 'line',
        id: 'line',
        paint: {
          'line-color': [
            'interpolate',
            ['linear'],
            ['get', 'dataValue'],
            ...valuesAndColors,
          ],
          'line-width': 5,
        },
        layout: {
          'line-cap': 'round',
          'line-join': 'round',
        },
      });
    });
```

**The used geojson**

```
{
    "features": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        25.00431796874952,
                        60.19175243531123
                    ],
                    [
                        25.070235937498865,
                        59.862435759471225
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 226
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        25.070235937498865,
                        59.862435759471225
                    ],
                    [
                        22.54338046874932,
                        59.27258194446978
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 256
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        22.54338046874932,
                        59.27258194446978
                    ],
                    [
                        19.120034975473317,
                        58.92048981178607
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 117
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        19.120034975473317,
                        58.92048981178607
                    ],
                    [
                        18.241128725473203,
                        59.27033287003081
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 114
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        25.100235937498866,
                        59.83743575947123
                    ],
                    [
                        25.03431796874952,
                        60.16675243531123
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 248
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        22.57338046874932,
                        59.24758194446978
                    ],
                    [
                        25.100235937498866,
                        59.83743575947123
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 202
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        19.150034975473318,
                        58.89548981178607
                    ],
                    [
                        22.57338046874932,
                        59.24758194446978
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 257
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        18.271128725473204,
                        59.245332870030815
                    ],
                    [
                        19.150034975473318,
                        58.89548981178607
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "dataValue": 292
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

Comment: There looks to be a `line-gradient` option you can use in the `paint` property.  See https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/line-gradient/